# Assigning subclass to a factory constructor in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

The `Key` class in Flutter has a `factory` constructor which works more like a variable.

```dart
abstract class Key {
  const factory Key(String value) = ValueKey<String>;

  // ...
}
```

But when I do something like that, I get an error:

```dart
class Foo {
  Foo.empty();
  const factory Foo(int i) = Bar; // Error
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  Bar() : super.empty();
}
```

Actually I didn't quite get what is the use of this factory constructor cum variable. Can anyone please explain.

Comment: One obvious problem would be that `Bar` does not have a `const` constructor, which your `Foo` factory constructor requires.

Comment: The other big problem is that you're using a redirecting constructor (from the `=`), and that requires that both constructors have the same parameters.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks sir, that worked. Although I never saw `=` being used in redirecting constructor calls, I've only seen `:` used for them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A constructor like:

```dart
const factory Key(String value) = ValueKey<String>;
```

is called a *redirecting factory constructor*. They're not well-known (even within the Dart and Flutter teams) since [they aren't mentioned in the Dart Language Tour](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/2009), but they're mentioned in [the Dart Language Specification](https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf) in (as of version 2.10) section 10.6.2:

> A *redirecting factory constructor* specifies a call to a constructor of another
> class that is to be used whenever the redirecting constructor is called.

Your attempt to use them:

> ```dart
> const factory Foo(int i) = Bar; // Error
> ```

doesn't work for two reasons:

- You declared the `Foo` factory constructor as `const`, but the default `Bar` constructor is not `const`.  Either remove `const` from the `Foo` factory constructor or make the `Bar` default constructor `const` (which also would require making the `Foo.empty` constructor `const`).
- Note that when you use a redirecting factory constructor with `=`, there's no opportunity for you to specify how to pass arguments.  That's because a redirecting factory constructor requires that both constructors have the same parameters.  Either remove the unused parameter from the `Foo` factory constructor or make `Bar`'s constructor take an `int` argument too.

You should pay attention to the errors that you get from static analysis; they explain the above two issues.  In DartPad, I get:

> A constant redirecting constructor can't redirect to a non-constant constructor.

and

> The redirected constructor 'Bar Function()' has incompatible parameters with 'Foo Function(int)'.